# Email addresses not showing in query when using LIKE '_@_%' - POSTGRE SQL

Tags: postgresql, sql-like, data-cleaning

I'm cleaning some user data and am trying to find any emails that were input into the "First Name" column. Ideally, I would run a simple function and any field with "@" in it will appear.

The code I'm using to find emails is

```
SELECT * FROM "Import File"
WHERE "First Name" LIKE '_@_%';
```

I got 0 results, so I tried

```
WHERE "First Name" LIKE '_@_%'
OR "First Name" LIKE '__@_%' 
OR "First Name" LIKE '___@_%'
```

and so forth.

The problem is I get a different number of results for each OR LIKE and typing it out every time will be tedious. Is there a faster function for this? (other than copy pasting)

Comment: You want to use the any characters wildcard twice, like `LIKE '%@%'`?

Comment: @stickybit We have an answer section for answers. Thanks

Comment: Have you read [the documentation for `LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html)? It explains how to use it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `LIKE` operations, the underscore character (`_`) is a single-character wildcard, whereas the percent character (`%`) is a multi-character wildcard.

So, to find if a column has an at symbol, you could just use this logic:

```
WHERE "First Name" LIKE '%@%'
```

...or...

```
WHERE POSITION('@' IN "First Name") > 0
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Very helpful